# vba coding to rearrange the dataset

Tags: vba, excel

I have a few range sets of data and it is every `7x12` cells and all arranged in columns, so I want to rearrange it into rows.
Some range sets may be empty, so I will ignore that range sets. The attached picture shows the current result and desired result. 
Thank you.
*Sample Image:* 

[image]

Comment: Your post only contains requirements and no particular efforts from your side that show your attempts to solve the problem. In order for us to be able to help you, you need to show what you did so far (code examples) and what problems you have in particular ("The code throws the exception ..."). Have a look at [this help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get started.

Comment: You say your data is every `7x12` but in your sample output it is every `4x5`. Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give this a try. Please look at the columns and update for your scenario

```
Public Sub DataRearrange()
    Dim LastRowInSet As Long, LastCol As Long, LastRowInTransposedData As Long, ColumnIncrease As Long
    Dim j As Long

    ' Change this to the width of your repeating data set
    ColumnIncrease = 4
    ' Change this to your relevant Sheet Name
    With Sheets("InsertYoursheetNameHere")
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        ' There's no point doing it if there's only one set so lets Exit
        If LastCol <= ColumnIncrease Then Exit Sub

        For j = ColumnIncrease + 1 To LastCol Step ColumnIncrease
            LastRowInSet = .Cells(.Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp).Row
            LastRowInTransposedData = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Range(.Cells(LastRowInTransposedData + 1, 1), .Cells(LastRowInTransposedData + LastRowInSet, ColumnIncrease)).Value2 = Range(.Cells(1, j), .Cells(LastRowInSet, j + ColumnIncrease - 1)).Value2
            Range(.Cells(1, j), .Cells(LastRowInSet, j + ColumnIncrease - 1)).Clear
        Next j
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I have solved the problem and now I have another question. Is that I want to copy every 29th cell and starting from C2 and to paste them at K5 onwards with the same spacing in between which is 29 for this case. my coding is below:     Sub Copy() 
     
    Dim lngRow As Long: lngRow = 1 
    Dim lngLoop As Long: lngLoop = 29 
    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(lngLoop, 1)) 
        Cells(lngLoop, 1).copy Cells(lngRow, "K3") 
        lngLoop = lngLoop + 29
        lngRow = lngRow + 29
    Loop 
     
End Sub

Comment: If this solved your question please mark it as the accepted answer (the tick to the left of it). You'll need to start a new question for your other problem I'm afraid